# How can I install 12.10 on a Sony Vaio Ultrabook (Windows 8)

Tags: installation, 12.10, live-usb

I have a Sony Vaio Ultrabook with an Intel i3 64 bit running Windows 8.

I booted into Ubuntu via USB and then tried to install and got this message each time:

> SORRY, UBUNTU 12.10 HAS EXPERIENCED AN INTERNAL ERROR

Then the screen goes black and i have to turn off via power button.
The "try it out" function works just fine it just will not install.

Answer (score 1):

New Vaio Ultrabook with UEFI?
I changed my BIOS to legacy prior to installing.

The steps to reproduce on my vaio were from powered down, hold down the Assist key to power it up. 
Brings up a slew of options, with BIOS being one of them.

Change your BIOS from UEFI to Legacy and see if that corrects the issue?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you think you could expand on it by providing steps to changing those BIOS settings that newer users might find helpful?

Comment: sure thing; good point